# Handle Button command in parent Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control the main content of which are shown as below

```
<ItemsControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding myCollection}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="lstExpander" >
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" Margin="0,0,0,0" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="100,0,0,0"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <local:AttributeExpander>/local:AttributeExpander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The items of this control are again user control i.e ConditionalAttributeExpander, which contains a button. When that button is click on the item in items control, I want the command to be handled in the parent control.

Comment: Throw an event out there

Comment: Give the owner of myCollection, which i suppose is a ViewModel, a property of type ICommand. Give your UserControl a dependency property of type ICommand which is internally bound to your button. And finally bind those two together. You might want to pass the instance as parameter.

Comment: @dowhilefor Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted :). I hope I can put it in answer how I did it as can help some one else also. Kindly review it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my AttrubuteExpander User Control I have defined a dependency property as follow

```
 public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DeleteCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DeleteCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for DeleteCommandCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DeleteCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("DeleteCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(AttrubuteExpander ), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
```

I have binded the DeleteCommand Property to a button which is present in my user control as shown below

```
 <Button Width="20" Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=my:AttributeExpander}, Path=DeleteCommand, Mode=OneWay}"
                            > 
                    </Button>
```

Now in the container of my Collection i.e my ViewModel I have deifned a property of type ICommand as follow and binded the Command property and dependency property of user control together and it is working fine

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand 
    {
        get 
        {
            if (deleteCommand == null)
            {
                deleteCommand = new RelayCommand(x => Remove(null));
            }

            return deleteCommand;
        }           
    }
```

and the xaml is as follow

```
<DataTemplate>
                <local:AttributeExpander DeleteConditionCommand="{Binding ElementName=lstExpander, Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"></local:AttributeExpander>
            </DataTemplate>
```